# Problema com retorno SQL

Tags: sql, query, return, filtro

Eu tenho as 3 seguintes tabelas: Clientes, Solicitacoes, Solicitacoes_descricao, que foram criadas da seguinte maneira:

Clientes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Solicitacoes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

solicitacao_descricao

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tabela solicitacoes faz ligação com a tabela cliente(cliente_id = id[tabela cliente]) e ligado a tabela solicitacao_descricao(solicitacao_descricao_id = id[tabela solicitacao_descricao])

Preciso de retorna um cliente que tenha feito mais de uma solicitacao_descricao!

Por exemplo preciso de todos os clientes que fez consulta e exame juntos. Como monto uma query nesse cenário para isso?

Answer (score 0):

```
select cli.nome, group_concat(solicitacoes_descricao_id) solicitacao_descricao
  from clientes cli, solicitacao_descricao sd, solitacoes sol
 where cli.id = sol.cliente_id
   and sol.solicitacoes_descricao_id = sd.id
 group by cli.nome
 having count(sol.solicitacoes_descricao_id) > 1
```

Comment: Eu quero o contrário, eu quero "TODAS" as pessoas que participaram de mais de uma solicitação. então o filtro tem q ser por mais de uma solicitação, por exemplo quero todos os cliente que participaram da solicitação com id 1,2,3(as 3 juntas).

Comment: fiz uma modificação, seria isso gustavo?

Comment: Eu vi, não seria.. pq tem filtro em cliente.. o único filtro seria na solicitacao_descricao... só quero o filtro nela o cliente é o que eu quero que retorna. Por exemplo quero todos os clientes que participaram da solicitacao 1,2,3,4 ... ai o sql me retorna uma lista de clientes

Comment: quais campos vc quer de retorno? coloquei sol.id id_solicitacao, sd.descricao, cli.id

Comment: pode ser só o cliente.nome, a modificação não vai funcionar pq o in funciona como vários OR e eu quero o contrário.. quero q seja obrigatório o cliente ter paricipado de 2 ou mais  solicitações para aparecer...Tinha que ser vários "AND" q funcione. Mas já tentei de várias formas não deu.

Comment: usei o group_concat, que vai trazer todas as solicitações de cada cliente com a condição de ter 2 ou mais solicitações

Comment: Quase isso, preciso apenas que sejam solicitações que escolher ao inves de ser >=2 como faço?

Comment: como não tenho o banco aqui, fica mais complicado de testar rs. mas ve se a mudança seria essa?

Comment: Mas ai volto para o problema de ter que ser obrigatório as solicitações para aparecer teria como conversarmos?

Comment: é pq voce colocou no comentario acima que precisava apenas solicitações que vc escolhesse ao inves de >=2

Comment: Então o cliente um, participa da solicitacao_descricao(3,8,13) as 3 juntas quero colocar um filtro assim, Todos os clientes que participaram da 3,8,13 solicitacoes juntas.